# Should we burninate this tag [once] and for all?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I was very surprised that the [once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/once) tag exists at all. It even has a tag description:

> Once: The code or operation is meant to fire only one time, typically only on the first execution. This tag can be useful because otherwise searching on "once" is all but useless. But, the search term "[once]" will restrict to only those questions where one-time operation is a key point.

Burninate?

Comment: yea not helpful. `once` is a valid function for the `on`/`off` event pattern, but that should be tied to `events`

Comment: But what if I was implementing something for backstage use for the hit musical? :p

Comment: This is [featured] ? It's the first time I see a burnination request with the [featured] tag. Something new ?

Comment: @JonasCz: Read the link that rene posted: https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/feb2016/burnination.md

Comment: Aha, so it's [that proposal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307068/make-it-easier-to-prevent-new-questions-being-added-in-a-tag/307124#307124) - nice to see that it's actually being done.

Comment: Should [these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bonce%5D+include+is%3Aquestion) be retagged to [tag:include-once]?

Comment: @Bergi include-once doesn't [seems too complex](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)

Comment: @Braiam: Sure it's not, but I don't know enough PHP to understand whether an own tag is warranted. There's also the much bigger [tag:require-once] tag that is similar.

Comment: I'm an expert in doing things [once]. Non-repeatable that is. Actually, all users are experts in this.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more, what exactly your beef with this tag is?

Comment: How about the [`.one()` method](http://api.jquery.com/one/) in jQuery? That could potentially be a good use for the tag, right?

Comment: Just a reminder to all you proactive editors out there: this post is a *discussion* on whether the tag should be burninated or not, it is **not** an open invitation to start editing at will, *regardless* of the request's score/popularity. Community consensus mush first be reached before any action is taken.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Using that logic, it's OK to have a tag for every function in jQuery? I don't think it helps at all.

Comment: @DavidG I'm asking, not assuming.

Comment: Finally, tag burnination requests are being taken seriously. 

Comment: @Sam What constitutes community consensus? Is there a standard?

Comment: @CubeJockey believe it or not, that's what we are trying to figure out.

Comment: @Braiam I just read over Rene's link, looks like it provides some structure via Shog's suggestion. Having participated before, I welcome this new process for burnination

Comment: @CubeJockey Step 3 of the proposal from Shog. Although, as previously mentioned, this is still all one large experiment.

Comment: There is an android library called Once, what happens when this is burninated and someone asks a question about that lib, tagging it [once] ?

Comment: @Tim: Either the tag description should be updated to make it clear that the tag is for that library or there should be a better tag name that contains "android".

Comment: @MikeMB: Good question. I made this post two years ago, so I don't really remember my original motivation. Today I feel like the tag is very broad so that it doesn't provide any additional value for classifying a question.

Comment: @TimCastelijns it would preferable that that library don't use plain [once] otherwise we would  have to continually disambiguate it

Comment: @FelixKling: My appologies - I only looked at the date of the answer by Kevin Reid and not of the question. I agree that it is very broad on its own, but I think it can be usefull for searching in conjunction with other tags, like "[c++],[include],[once]". But in general, im neither in favor, nor against burniating it - as long as we don't make it a synonym idempotent.

Comment: I think we need to change the title a few more times before taking any action.

Comment: While these kind of posts have an history with [puns](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295583/why-do-people-have-a-little-pun-with-their-retag-and-burninate-requests) I can see why the CM-team rather have a semi-professional title now that the post get featured on the main site as well @adv12

Comment: @rene, wasn't calling out anyone in particular.  Personally I usually gag at the "clever" titles; just found the edit history funny.

Comment: I probably would not have clicked this link if I didn't see "burninate" in the corner of my screen (nice trogdor reference). But you got my vote to remove the tag :)

Comment: The best use of [tag:once] I can think of is [`once()` in Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=once/1). But I don’t think this justifies its preservation – misuse is much more probable.

Comment: It looks like this tag was burned [once] and for all

Comment: @rene you are wrong. the title was changed to the "funny" title only after it was featured. I think it might have changed again after i complained that silly comments get removed but the silly title is here to stay (cause thats a weird double standard)

Answer (score 40):

[idempotent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idempotent) and [once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/once) do not mean the same thing. They are not synonyms.

An [idempotent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idempotent) process can be run multiple times, but always has the same result.

[once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/once) asserts that the process can only be run a single time. It could be effectively *idempotent*, but it could also explicitly fail if called multiple times.

For instance if every time I click a button I get a warning then it is *idempotent*, if the first time I click it I get a warning but subsequent times it does nothing then that ran *once*.

Some languages and frameworks have constructs that facilitate run-once patterns, for instance [`static` constructors in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx), or [`$.one()` in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/one/) (to give two very different implementations and interpretations). Neither of these is *idempotent* (at least within the context/scope).

Whether [once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/once) is a meaningful tag is the real question - there are plenty of [questions tagged with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/once) but I'm not sure it makes sense as a tag. It's a language agnostic concept but almost every question is asking something very specific - 'How do I make something run once in X' kind of questions.

As such I don't think it adds value.

Comment: There used to be a list of questions related to burnination (can't find it at the moment) which included things like "can someone be an expert [once]" etc. How does the tag fit in there?

Comment: There are also **once** facilities for shared libraries/threads where something is only done [once in a system](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_once).  While, I think it might have some technical merit for an ideal world I agree that the tag name is going to promote abuse.

Comment: FYI depending on the context idempotent may also mean that a if a function is applied to an output of itself, it will be the same as the initial output, ie, if `f(f(x))=f(x)`, then `f(x)` is idempotent

Comment: @artlessnoise: Interestingly there are no hits for [tags pthreads+once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/once%20pthreads?mode=all), which your link ought to match.

Comment: As soon as someone states that a tag `implies` something, you know it's being misused...

Comment: @chiliNUT yes, though that's even less applicable to _once_. When I posted the only answer stated that they were synonymous, so I addressed that, but I think a detailed discussion on idempotency may be rather off-topic here.

Comment: @Rhumborl don't get too hung up on my word choice, while rather sesquipedalian I can get rather sloppy at times. I think once clearly indicates that something should be run only one time.

Answer (score 17):

The tag description seems to suggest that someone thought it would be useful as a search filter:

> The code or operation is meant to fire only one time, typically only on the first execution. This tag can be useful because otherwise searching on "once" is all but useless. But, the search term "[once]" will restrict to only those questions where one-time operation is a key point.

Given the smattering of usages documented here so far and the fairly small question count (less than 150), I would argue it doesn't meet that goal.

Additionally, the tag name is vague and likely to be misinterpreted or misused.

Verdict: Burninate.

Answer (score 7):

This tag is being used for jQuery, JavaScript, PHP, Android, Java and Python. In most cases that didn't include PHP tagged questions it was used to mean that it is "only one time", evidently from the titles, examples:

- [Making Pygame Play Sound ONCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366020/making-pygame-play-sound-once)
- [How to run a for loop multiple times in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11082937/792066)
- [How to show splash screen only when the app starts "fresh"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7682439/792066)
- [Calling an if function two times inside a jsf tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12697974/792066)
- [android stop service and run service just once time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127540/android-stop-service-and-run-service-just-once-time)
- [Android SQLiteDatabase insert method only work once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150957/android-sqlitedatabase-insert-method-only-work-once)
- [jquery run each only one time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31496231/jquery-run-each-only-one-time)
- [jquery prevent function running more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30175113/jquery-prevent-function-running-more-than-once)
- [loading of javascript function only once using .one() API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27676497/loading-of-javascript-function-only-once-using-one-api)
- [How to restrict my objects to call a method only once in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34282221/792066)
- [PHP Class - How to connect to the database only once](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32954301/792066)
- [How do I execute code once and only once in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34203623/792066)

Other less used is the phrase "at once" which means "immediately":

- [In python how to use all items in list at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140499/in-python-how-to-use-all-items-in-list-at-once)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287076/sprite-animation-two-animations-at-once

PHP and Objetive-C have functions which part of the name is "once", like "include_once" and "dispatch_once", which are the most easier to find examples of:

- [BOOL vs. dispatch_once_t](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26513886/792066)
- [objective-c error: no viable overloaded =](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18335451/792066)
- [PHP include var from file in a file that is then included in other files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34272451/792066)

Of the later, some are accompanied with the tags include and dispatch, which may be removed along with the once tag.

In the above cases, there weren't found any question that doesn't have a more fitting tag. Most of them require some non-trivial editing in the way of improving title, or removing scruff from the body, but I couldn't find reasons to close any of them from a cursory glance.

Comment: May not be relevant but there's also the old `C` [#pragma once](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once).

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon none of the questions were about C, I would say that if they are using a tag at all it isn't [once]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, as an alternative to deletion, renaming to [execute-once] (in preference to [run-once]), which seems to express the intention more clearly. If only the name is the problem, this is useful, but it still needs to be clear that that category of questions is useful. It might still need manual review of the tagged questions.

There is also a comment from 2014-06-30 by Hans Passant on [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261975/merge-network-share-and-network-shares-tags] suggesting that there is something wrong with deleting any tags at all — if that is still the case, seems to be a reason not to do anything!

Comment: It is definitely not the case that no tags should ever be deleted. That's absurd. Tagspace is a resource constrained by effective attention; tags that add only clutter are actively detracting from the usefulness of the site and adding additional effort to maintain it.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: It sounds absurd to me too, yet that seems to be implied by Hans Passant’s post!

Comment: Hans was apparently speaking from a perspective that, because users burninating tags manually can often make lousy edits that then bump the posts for no good reason, manual tag burnination should be eschewed in favor of having the developers do the job... resulting in lousy edits that *don't* bump those posts and the loss of all chance to close bad posts, retag sensibly, and make any other helpful edits to posts that need it in that tag. This is inferior. Tags should be burninated carefully, not with a simple database query.

Answer (score -33):

**This tag as its excerpt describes it is a synonym of [idempotent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idempotent).**

Whether [once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/once) is turned into a synonym or destroyed, the situation at the end should be that good questions on the subject are tagged with [idempotent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idempotent).

Given that [once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/once) (from a quick skim of its questions) seems to attract *adequately* appropriate questions, it seems like keeping it as a synonym is worthwhile (except for [the problem that hardly anyone will be able to vote that synonym in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252690/what-privilege-should-30k-users-get/270336#270336), but if this project has moderator attention anyway…).

(Though: [idempotent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idempotent) currently has *fewer* questions than [once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/once). But I haven't checked whether it has fewer good-and-relevant questions.)

Comment: How is something that runs once a synonym of something that can be run multiple times?

Comment: @TylerH They're slightly different, but they're both about something that _when invoked/triggered repeatedly any number of times, has only 1 times its effect_. Many events/calls/inputs, one effect/output.

Comment: (Note for precision: The previous statement is true about idempotence as meant when discussing _side effects_. An idempotent _pure function,_ as a mathematician would think of first, needs to be described in different terms and doesn't relate to “once” as much. But the side effect meaning is common in programming.)

Comment: Most usages I connect to `once` are very different to idempotent because those things should only ever run a single time because they usually have side effects that would make an additional execution break.

Comment: Although I'm not active in any of the two tags, I'd really not expect them to be synonyms. Idempotence imho means you hav the same effect when you call it with the same input, but might have a different result with a different input. Once means that something - althoug it might be called multiple times with multiple inputs - is executed only `once` (usually with the first set of inputs) and can e.g. refer to guard mechanisms, that ensure that behavior (like `std::once` or static variable initialization in c++)

Comment: If anything, [tag:once] should be a synonym of [tag:memoize], rather than [tag:idempotent]. And even that isn't really a best match. Synonyms should be used for things that are **exactly** the same, like typos or alternative names.