# Should we merge the tag [double-checked] into [double-checked-locking]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, retag-request

I observe that as at 2016-02-10 the tag [double-checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double-checked) has a mere 10 questions, which do not look to me significantly different from those under [double-checked-locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double-checked-locking). (Both tags also apparently have 0 followers.) The name [double-checked-locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double-checked-locking) is better as it is more explicit.

The description of [double-checked-locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double-checked-locking):

> Double-checked locking is a software design pattern used to reduce the overhead of acquiring a lock by first testing the locking criterion without actually acquiring the lock.

The description of [double-checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double-checked):

> For questions regarding the safety and (safe) implementation of double-checked locking.

This makes [double-checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double-checked) a rather specific subset of [double-checked-locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double-checked-locking); since one would always want to implement it safely, it seems to me to add little value.

***N.B.***

*I see many questions tagged [synonym-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synonym-request) (request a _new_ tag synonym) which seem to belong under [retag-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/retag-request)*.

Comment: Unrelated: there's a difference between merging a not-so-common tag into another and making a common tag a synonym of another. This request definitely doesn't need a synonym, and sometimes it's easier to do a merge instead of making synonyms.

Comment: I fail to see how either of them are tags in the first place.

Comment: It's possible that we should, but maybe we should double-check each one of them...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Having a quick look at these two tags, there seem to be no reason to have both of them.

The name [double-checked-locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double-checked-locking) is clearly better as it is more explicit and also has more questions on it.   [double-checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double-checked) only has 11 questions that are all old.

**I see little need for a synonym, therefore I think someone should just retag these 11 questions by hand.**

If you don't agree please down vote this answer, assuming no downstate in the next day someone should just do the retag.

Comment: Pretty sure [we're using the process where burninates have to hit 20 and be featured first now](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307068/make-it-easier-to-prevent-new-questions-being-added-in-a-tag/307124#307124).

Comment: @NathanTuggy, but this is not a "locking" or blacklisting of a tag, it is the editing of tags on **only** 11 questions.

Comment: So? That process is not designed for blacklisting only. See e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258571/should-we-burninate-the-tag-once

Comment: @NathanTuggy for just 11 questions going through that process is overboard.

Answer (score 5):

I went ahead and retagged all of them.

List of retagged questions:

- [Is this code Double Checked Locking safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408120/is-this-code-double-checked-locking-safe)
- [Double checked locking on C++: new to a temp pointer, then assign it to instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498998/double-checked-locking-on-c-new-to-a-temp-pointer-then-assign-it-to-instance)
- [How to show that the double-checked-lock pattern with Dictionary's TryGetValue is not threadsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624301/how-to-show-that-the-double-checked-lock-pattern-with-dictionarys-trygetvalue-i)
- [Mike Ash Singleton: Placing @synchronized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418780/mike-ash-singleton-placing-synchronized)
- [Java double checked locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625118/java-double-checked-locking)
- [What's wrong with this fix for double checked locking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945232/whats-wrong-with-this-fix-for-double-checked-locking)
- [Does "Double Checked Locking" work in ColdFusion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552839/does-double-checked-locking-work-in-coldfusion)
- [Is this broken double checked locking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330178/is-this-broken-double-checked-locking)
- [Resetting a field lazy-loaded with the double-check idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307073/resetting-a-field-lazy-loaded-with-the-double-check-idiom)
- [Double checked locking Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157198/double-checked-locking-article)