# It was [once] but now it gets [single]

Tags: discussion, tags

[Should we burninate this tag [once] and for all?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258571/4928642)

Now there is a [single](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/single) tag:

- [RxJava introduced Single<T>. How do I convert an Observable<T> to a Single<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36627927/4928642)
- [alert once in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36627988/4928642)

It has only 2 questions, but 20 followers.
So I can say that number of followers is ten times greater then number of questions :)

Maybe that tag had some meaning?

Comment: better remove those tags to prevent we have to [double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double) the work later....

Comment: @rene, what about [this solution](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316631/4928642)?

Comment: What are you asking here? To burninate [tag:single]? Or are you asking what its meaning is?

Comment: @Tunaki, it's a discussion. I'm asking mentions about this tag and about [tag:once] tag. Why are there so many followers? Do we need to keep the tag, and if so, should we rename it to make more clear? Do we need to keep it as a type for rx-java only?

Comment: The two questions have been re-tagged. The tag itself will be deleted at 03:00 UTC

Comment: @rene, but it means that 20 users will lost subscription on it. Why did they subscribe it?

Comment: I dunno, when they notice they either complain on meta or blame the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room, both is fine with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, questions were retagged, tag disappeared and 20 users lost subscription on something.

Answer (score 3):

If we look at the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627927/rxjava-introduced-singlet-how-do-i-convert-an-observablet-to-a-singlet) that added [single](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/single) to the system you can see the OP is talking about [`Single`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/single.html) from ReactiveX.  I think it would be okay to have a tag on this it just needs a wiki and an excerpt to go with it so if people use it incorrectly we can remove it.

That said a tag named [single](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/single) is going to used incorrectly more then it will be used correctly.  If we want a specific tag for the ReactiveX Single then I suggest [reactivex-single](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactivex-single).

Comment: No, let's not do that. That tag is prone to be abused due to its overly broad meaning. No tag wiki can fix that ....

Comment: @rene I have added to the answer and explained that we should not keep the tag as named.

Comment: Isn't rx-java not enough? Given that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rx+single) only renders about 500 results

Comment: OP here. I'm ok with removing this granularity. Y'all would have a much better idea of how big of a topic rx-java is to begin with!